# Converting entire table column of varchar/varbinary to xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have a table with one of the columns as varbinary, which actually contains base64 encoded string.

```
Table: Messages
Id        |   int
Payload   |   varbinary(MAX)
```

I can see its contents using

```
select cast(Payload as varchar(max)) from Messages
```

However, I need to convert the whole column to XMl, so that these kind of cast is not required and I can store much longer strings as XML. For a single entry I can do something like

```
select convert(xml, (select top 1 cast(payload as varchar(max)) 
                     from Messages
                    )
              ) as PayLoad 
for XML PATH('');
```

How do I convert the whole table to xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID INT,PayLoad VARBINARY(MAX));
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
                 (1,CAST('AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDmRXhpZg' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
                ,(2,CAST('AAAAJAAAISodpAAQAAAABAAAIVJydAAEAAAASAAAQz' AS VARBINARY(MAX)));  

--simple output
SELECT * 
FROM #temp;

--casted output
SELECT ID,CAST(PayLoad AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PayLoad 
FROM #temp;

--AS XML
SELECT ID
      ,CAST(PayLoad AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PayLoad
FROM #temp 
FOR XML PATH('Row'),ROOT('root');

--EDIT: new SELECT
--As table with Payload as XML
SELECT ID
      ,(SELECT CAST(PayLoad AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('PayLoad'),TYPE) AS PayLoad
FROM #temp 

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: This will return the whole table in a single query. What i want instead is that I get all the rows, like in a normal select statement, with the base64 columns displayed for each row as an XML. Something like 'SELECT Id, CAST(PayLoad AS varchar(MAX)) as PayLoad FROM Messages'. This will return me the entire table as a grid with the payload in decoded string. I want it to be XML instead for the each row

Comment: Is the content of your base64 string an XML? I added one more select to my code to give you what you are writing, but I doubt, that this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

How about using `for xml path`?

```
select cast(Payload as varchar(max))
from Messages
for xml path ('');
```

You can include the appropriate annotations.  You can also have multiple columns.  The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx).

Comment: This will return the whole table in a single query. What i want instead is that I get all the rows, like in a normal select statement, with the base64 columns displayed for each row as an XML. Something like 'SELECT Id, CAST(PayLoad AS varchar(MAX)) as PayLoad FROM Messages'. This will return me the entire table as a grid with the payload in decoded string. I want it to be XML instead for the each row